# PHP - Dynamically apply parsing rules to text, and save to dynamic fields

Tags: php, database-design, code-reviews, laravel

OK, so I have been at this problem for the last few days, and I must admit - **I am stuck**.

I am trying to make a web application, where users can upload documents **or** send inbound e-mails.

Each document or email will be added to a `stream`. So a stream holds all the docs/mails.

Now, what I want to allow my users are the following:

1. Users should be able to add ´fields´ to a stream. A field is essentially just a dynamic variable, that users can set. So for example, if a user uploads a large text file, they can eg. create below `fields`:

```
id | name
-----------------------
 1 | Order number
 2 | Tracking reference
```

2. Users can then add `parsing rules` to each `field`. A parsing rule can consist of multiple methods. For example:

   - `remove_empty_lines`
   - `text_replace`
   - `regex_text_replace`

Users can apply as many parsing rules to the text string as they want. Everytime a new parsing rule has been applied, the **new and updated** text string will be stored in `parsing_rule_results`

OK so above describes the workflow, that a user can setup for **each** document/email, and above is bound pr. `stream`.

Now, what I want to achieve is the following:

1. For each new document/email that is added to my application, I need to check what `fields` is defined for the specific stream.
2. For each field defined, I need to run the string through each `parsing_rule`, and
3. ultimately, once the string has been run through each parsing rule, the **end** result should be dynamically saved to that **specific** document/email. Something like:

```
id | document_id | email_id | field | data
---------------------------------------------------
 1 | 5           | null     | 3     | 5000251
 2 | 5           | null     | 4     | AJIWO4124124J
 3 | 6           | null     | 3     | 92841
 4 | 6           | null     | 4     | KKLJPEPQ9102
 5 | 6           | null     | 3     | E-Order2000
 6 | null        | 2        | 4     | OOCLTCU8291LK
```

Which can be translated into:

**Stream: 1**

**Document ID # 5:**

1. `order_number`= "5000251"
2. `tracking_number` = "AJIWO4124124J"

**Document ID # 6:**

1. `order_number`= "92841"
2. `tracking_number` = "KKLJPEPQ9102"

**Email ID # 2:**

1. `order_number`= "E-Order2000"
2. `tracking_number` = "OOCLTCU8291LK"

Below is the beginning of my database design - **but without "field results"**.

[image: My database setup]

This is the code I have so far (models):

`Stream.php`

```
    // A stream can have many documents
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Document::class);
    }

    //A stream can have many e-mails
    public function emails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Email::class);
    }
     //A stream can have many fields
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Field::class);
    }
    //A stream have fields, which then have parsing rules.
    public function parsingRules()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ParsingRule::class, Field::class);
    }
```

`Document.php`

```
    //A document belongs to a Stream.
    public function stream()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class);
    }

    // A document will have fields.
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Field::class, 'stream_id', 'stream_id');
    }
```

`Email.php`

```
    // An email belongs to a Stream.
    public function stream()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class);
    }

    //An email will have fields.
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Field::class, 'stream_id', 'stream_id');
    }
```

`Field.php`

```
   // A field belongs to a Stream
    public function stream()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class);
    }

    // A field can have many parsing rules.
    public function parsingRules()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ParsingRule::class);
    }
```

`ParsingRule.php`

```
    //A parsing rule belongs to a field.
    public function field()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Field::class);
    }
```

`ParsingRuleResult.php`

```
    //A parsing rule, belongs to a field rule.
    public function fieldrule()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FieldRule::class);
    }

    // A parsing ruleresult, belongs to a document.
    public function document()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Document::class);
    }
```

I believe the real problem I have lies in my understanding of relationships, and how I should dynamically apply above logic.

Let's imagine I have a class, that will be called whenever a new document/email is being added:

`ApplyParsingRules.php`

```
    public function parse(Stream $stream, Document $document)
    {    
         $text = $document->text;
         $fields = $stream->fields()->get();


         //1. get all $parsing_rules for each $fields.

         //2. parse $text by using each $parsing_rule

         //3. save the end result of $text by document/email specific and field.

    }
```

As you can see, I can fetch the stream details as well as the fields for the specific stream.

However - how can I:

1. Make it so it allows **both** Email and Document, depending on what is being added? (Above only allows Document)
2. Run through each **field**, and subsequently parse through each **parsing_rule** and save the end result, so it's specific for each document/email

I hope above is somewhat clear. This post got a lot longer than first expected.

Comment: I believe, if you remove redundant and distracting code with relationships you already have in the diagram, it would be easier to read and understand.
At first, I was confused, thought that you have 1 stream of data from which you would like to compose documents/emails. But the diagram helped. So, you want to upload a file, *decompose* it to an ordered list of fields (you call it a stream). Each file will be represented as _one_ stream. After, you want to be able to compose a result from the stream. A result can be a type of Email or Document. => de/composing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow the `parse()` function parse both `Document` and `Email`, you can create an interface, e.g. `TextContainer` that `Document` and `Email` implement. Something like:

```
interface TextContainer {
    function getText(): string;
    function setText(string $text);
    function save();
}

class ApplyParsingRules {

    public function parse(Stream $stream, TextContainer $container)
    {    
         $text = $container->getText();
         $fields = $stream->fields()->get();

         //1. get all $parsing_rules for each $fields.

         //2. parse $text by using each $parsing_rule

         //3. save the end result of $text by document/email specific and field.
         $container->setText($text);
         $container->save();
    }
}
```

I actually prefer `parse()` to return the result and let the caller decide what to do with the result, i.e.

```
class ApplyParsingRules {

    public function parse(Stream $stream, TextContainer $container): string
    {    
         $text = $container->getText();
         $fields = $stream->fields()->get();

         //1. get all $parsing_rules for each $fields.

         //2. parse $text by using each $parsing_rule

         return $text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In regards to removing `Documents` and `Emails` table: I don't think I can place the `text` in the Streams table, since a stream can have many different documents/emails - all with different text content?

Comment: Ah, I see. So, if a `Streams` can have many `Documents` and `Emails` then is it right that `Fields` belong to `Documents`? In that case you'd need `Fields` to have foreign key to `Documents` and `Emails`.

Comment: I would argue that `Fields` belongs to a Stream, because the field values are the same for **all** `Documents` and `Emails` - i.e. they are not "bound" by a document or email. All documents and emails just needs to be parsed according to each field.

Comment: @oliverbj I see, the database design is fine then. I updated my answer

Comment: would `Document` and `Email` then contain `getText`, `setText` etc?

Comment: Yes. Note that you can also put them in a super class.

Comment: I don't see how I can use the `TextContainer` interface to get the content like: `$container->getText()` - sinec the `TextContainer $container` - does not return anything - it's only an interface? How can I access for example a documents content, if I only typehint `Stream $stream`?

Comment: The `Document` and `Email` classes would need to implement the interface. If you look at the `ApplyParsingRules::parse()` method, all it needs to do its job is the `$text`, it doesn't need to know whether the text comes from a `Document`, `Email` or some other kind of objects that might be implemented in the future as long as they implement the `TextContainer` interface.

Comment: But why does the `parse()` function in `ApplyParsingRules` also need to have typehinted the `TextContainer $container` ? If I add that, how do I pass it as an argument to the `parse()` function?

Comment: Since you want to be able to pass either `Document` or `Email`, to `parse()`, they need to have a common interface. After you implement the new interface in `Document` and `Email`, you can just pass both of them, e.g. `parse(new Stream(), new Document());` and `parse(new Stream(), new Email());` will work.